# Zero the excess digits of an array

Tags: rust

I wrote some code that set the last few elements of an array to zero. I call these last elements the "excess":

```rust
const MAX_DIGITS: usize = 20;
pub fn zero_excess_digits(digits: &mut [u8; MAX_DIGITS], n_digits: usize) {
    for i in n_digits..MAX_DIGITS {
        digits[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

However, Clippy considers this a [`needless_range_loop`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#needless_range_loop) and suggests I write the code like this:

```rust
const MAX_DIGITS: usize = 20;
pub fn zero_excess_digits_iter_for(digits: &mut [u8; MAX_DIGITS], n_digits: usize) {
    for d in digits.iter_mut().take(MAX_DIGITS).skip(n_digits) {
        *d = 0;
    }
}
```

Usually when I've used Clippy, it's given me solid advice. But in this case, I just don't see it. I've tried both versions in Godbolt/Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/7G8McseKs

1. it optimizes my original version to a call to `memset` (12 lines of asm);
2. for the `.iter_mut()` version, it generates code for the loop (30 lines of asm! Unacceptable!)
3. I tried using a `.for_each()` instead of `for ...` and it went down to 24 lines of asm.

Is there some deep insight from Clippy that I'm missing? Is there a more idiomatic way of writing this "zero the excess" code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a simpler and more idiomatic solution:

```
digits[n_digits..].fill(0);
```

You could also do:

```
for d in &mut digits [n_digits..MAX_DIGITS] {
    *d = 0;
}
```

However, these work slightly differently then your original. If n_digits is > MAX_DIGITS, the slice versions will panic on the slice. But your original version will do nothing, because the range is considered empty.

Comment: Brilliant! I did not know about `.fill()`!